# Gravity Forms Alignment

Tags: css, gravity-forms-plugin

I need help aligning gravity forms on my website https://www.shiftins.com.

On my homepage, the field aligns left and the button is directly below it. How do I put them inline?

I tried looking for the css class "simple-quote" but could not find it anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: I've added the old positioning of the form right below the main text. I would like that exact alignment and positioning just in the black bar. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

give the list items display:inline; and the label and input div display:inline-block

```
#field_1_1, #field_1_2 { display: inline; }
#field_1_1 .gfield_label, #field_1_2 .gfield_label { display: inline-block; width: 20%; }
#field_1_1 .ginput_container, #field_1_2 .ginput_container { display: inline-block; width: 80%; }
```

Then play with widths for label and inputs for desired output.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a noob. Can you please be more specific as to which lines of code I need to modify?

Comment: This did not work for me. Any other suggestions? I tried float: right; and float: left; for different containers with no luck.

Comment: I did not understand very well what you want to achieve, do you want the form to be in a full width bar? the fileds all one next to eachother horizontally inline with the button on right? because how it is set up now, the form in a column which is 50% width. with the "Don't Want To Fill Out a Quote Form?" next  to it taking up the other 50%